# Dark theme word processor for ubuntu or the web? Ideally that doesn't change every other application

Tags: themes, word-processor

I enjoy the way most of my applications look, but I wanted something like LibreOffice with a dark theme. The only ways I could find to make LibreOffice have a different look though involved changing the theme that every application in Ubuntu uses.

I just need:

- to edit text
- a dark theme
- the ability to bold / italicize text
- a way to make bullet point lists

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.1 with gnome-flashback. I am just looking for an application, web-based or desktop, that could do these things but could not find anything for the life of me. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, LibreOffice can be themed using Firefox themes. Go to `Tools > Options > LibreOffice > Personalization > Own Theme > Select Theme`

Comment: I tried the Firefox themes but they only seem to affect the toolbar area of LibreOffice. I was mostly interested in the document area where I write.

Comment: So you mean a dark background (paper) or the area behind the "paper"?

Comment: You can adapt the color schemes somwhere next to "Personalization" as well

Comment: Ah you're right, that's perfect actually. It was under Appearance and Custom Colors - quite a lot of customization is possible. Searching for "theme" was leading me down the wrong road. If you put your comment as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, LibreOffice is quite customizable.

You can go to <kbd>Tools</kbd>→<kbd>Options</kbd>→<kbd>LibreOffice</kbd>→<kbd>Tools</kbd>→<kbd>Appearance</kbd> to customize the colors of LibreOffice. There, you can basically change every color ever used in LO.